# Is this random variable continuous or discrete?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Here's this random variable with a given $CDF_X$:

| $x<1$ | $1\le x<2$ | $2\le x<3$ | $3\le x<4$ | $4\le x$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0 $ | $0.2$ | $0.35$ | $0.9$ | $1$ |

A friend of mine says that $P\left(X=1\right)=0.2$, $P\left(X=2\right)=0.35-0.2=0.15$, $P\left(X=3\right)=0.9-0.35=0.55$, $P\left(X=4\right)=1-0.9=0.1$.

I'm ok with all that but at the same time he says that the random variable is **continuous** and that puzzles me.

If a variable is continuous, shouldn't we have zero probability for every point?

So is this random variable continuous or discrete?

Comment: It is a discrete r.v. taking only the values $1,2,3$ and $4$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, @KaviRamaMurthy , that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF is the function where you put in a value $x$ and get out the probability $\Pr(X\leq x)$.

If this function jumps at a point, there is a positive probability of taking that exact value. So we know $\Pr(X\leq 1)=0.2$, but $\Pr(X\leq x)=0$ for every $x<1$ - the only way this can happen is if all of the probability $0.2$ corresponds to taking a value of exactly $1$.

Similarly, if the CDF is constant on an interval, that means the probability of a value strictly inside that interval is $0$. Since $\Pr(X\leq x)=\Pr(X\leq 1)$ for any $1\leq x< 2$, we know that $\Pr(1<X<x)=0$.

Since this CDF consists only of jumps between constant sections, it is the CDF of a purely discrete random variable.